# vmware player performance tuning

Tags: performance, boost, compilation, vmware-player, ace-tao

I did some compilation (ACE TAO, and Boost C++ library) in vmware player virtualmachine environment. I find I was unable to tolerate the performance.

My machine is T410(i7 620, 6G memory and 5400 harddriver). The installed OS is Ubuntu 12.04 and then I installed vmware player, where the hosted OS is XP. I allocated (3G,2 core for 15G) for VMware player.

For example, for Boost, the bootstrap.bat takes about 3 hours to complete in XP while it is only several seconds in ubuntu. For ACE TAO compilation, it takes 2 days in hosted XP but only less 3 hours in Ubuntu.

I checked task manger in hosted XP. CPU usage keeps about 12%, and only 300M~ memory are really used. Since both CPU and memory are not bottleneck, the problem should be at Disk side.

Because it is not possible to repace new hard driver, I wonder if there is some guide for Vmware player performance tunning, especially for hard driver?

This is link from vmware site 
http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&docType=kc&docTypeID=DT_KB_1_1&externalId=1008885

But the tools vmware-vdiskmanager in the link does not exist in my side.. How to check snapshot of my machine. Seems there is no snapshot generated in my machine.

Comment: I know nothing about VMWare Player, but on VirtualBox Boost bootstraping takes about the same time as it does on the host itself: a few seconds...

Comment: @IgorR.How did you achieve that? I installed virtualbox this afternoon. I assign two cores and 3G memory for Virtualbox, stop most of service. The boostrap.bat still have not response me after 30 minutes.. Have you made any other optimization besides memory?  I checked CPU and memory. CPU is 100%(cmd.exe for bootstrap.bat takes less 60% and system idel process is about 40%.. Memory is still not bottleneck).

Comment: No optimizations are required, it just works as is. How long does it take on your host machine itself?

Comment: Thanks @IgorR. I think I have identify root cause. It is caused by disk write access issue in my virtualbox.. It seems compilation(Disk write) is more fast in Virtaulbox than VMWware player.